# Как сделать интерфейс для изменения JS-кода веб-страницы?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Есть у меня сайт, на котором в зависимости от времени и дня недели выводится разный текст. Вот так выглядит код для выведения этого текста:

```
if (day == 1) 
{
    if ((h >= 0) && (h < 20)) { document.getElementById("marquee").innerHTML='Следующий эфир — «<b>Информационный салат</b>», сегодня в двадцать часов ровно';} 
    else if ((h >= 20) && (h < 21)) { document.getElementById("marquee").innerHTML='Сейчас в эфире — «<b>Информационный салат</b>»';}
    else if ((h >= 21) && (h <= 23)) { document.getElementById("marquee").innerHTML='Следующий эфир — «<b>Бухтельная</b>» завтра в двадцать часов ровно';}
} 

else if (day == 2) 
{
    if ((h >= 0) && (h < 20)) { document.getElementById("marquee").innerHTML='Следующий эфир — «<b>Бухтельная</b>» сегодня в двадцать часов ровно';} 
    else if ((h >= 20) && (h < 21)) { document.getElementById("marquee").innerHTML='Сейчас в эфире — «<b>Бухтельная</b>»';}
    else if ((h >= 21) && (h <= 23)) { document.getElementById("marquee").innerHTML='Следующий эфир — «<b>117,2 RPM</b>» завтра в двадцать часов ровно';}
}
```

...и так далее.

Так выводится расписание эфиров одного радио. Каждую неделю что-нибудь меняется, и менять планируемый текст приходится руками.

А можно ли написать на отдельной странице некий интерфейс для этого? Чтобы была таблица с расписанием, и из этого расписания сами строились эти фразы — «сейчас в эфире…», следующий эфир…» и пр. Ввёл в форму новую программу или гостя, нажал условный Submit — планируемый текст изменился.

В какую сторону копать?

Comment: В сторону php и sql сервера, может быть Ajax и JSon, может еще какую связку технологий =) ибо много их

Comment: Пропарсить страницу и подставить данные - всё что вам нужно. Насколько я понял, вещание на одной странице. Обновлять инфу через Ajax, админка не нужна.